# How to set bitmap according to the image size?

Tags: android, bitmap, imagebutton

I am trying to set bitmap to imagebutton  but image size change

My Image xml is

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_ChoosePicFIrst"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" 
                    android:background="@drawable/choose_pic"
                    android:tag="PIC1" />
```

i want to set image size accoring to the "@drawable/choose_pic" size

after choosing image from gallery i am convertin it to bitmap and it change the imagebutton size please give me some solution ?

Comment: Show the screenshot or image of your `choose_pic`. What is the resolution of your image ?

Answer (score 1):

//for that use ImageView with src

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button_ChoosePicFIrst"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" 

                    android:src="@drawable/choose_pic"
                    android:tag="PIC1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `ImageButton` you need to set your image in property `android:src=""` not as background of your `ImageButton`.

So set your image in `src` property and remove background as below:

```
     <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button_ChoosePicFIrst"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:src="@drawable/choose_pic"
                android:tag="PIC1" />
```

**EDITED:**

**Difference between `android:background"` and `android:src"`**

`android:background` exists for all the view. As the name suggests this is what is going to be there in the background.

`android:src` exists for `ImageViews` and its subclasses. You can think of this as the foreground. Because `ImageView` is a subclass of `View` you even have `android:background` for that.

If you set an image to be the background of your `ImageView`, then the image will scale to whatever size the `ImageView` is. Other than that, src is a foreground image and background is a background image.

The `src` to an `ImageView` has additional features:

- different [scaling types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)
- `adjustViewBounds` for setting bounds to match image dimensions
- some transformations such as alpha-setting

And more that you may find in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Comment: GrlsHu, can you please differentiate between property src and background. I have come to know that I can set two images to a ImageView, one using src property and the other (as backdrop to src) using background-property. Are there any other differences that you can highlight?